# SMB Connector Grounding for S/PDIF Coax

Tags: coax, spdif

I'm transmitting coax level S/PDIF over an SMB connector, and I'm wondering if the "body" pins (all pins that aren't the center) should be left floating, or if they should be connected to ground.

As I understand it, RCA Coax S/PDIF does expect the ground to be connected, rather than floating, which leads me to believe that the "body" pins should be connected to ground.

I'm using this [Molex 73100-0259](https://www.molex.com/webdocs/datasheets/pdf/en-us/0731000259_RF_COAX_CONNECTORS.pdf) connector, FWIW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the "body" pins must be grounded in order to ground the shield of the coax cable.